# PreparedStatement in a loop, how to use

Tags: java, loops, prepared-statement, derby, javadb

I'm trying to store all the items that were created in the `ITEM` table and I wonder if I can do that:

```
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    //String sql = "INSERT INTO ITEM (ID, TYPE, TITEL, UITGELEEND) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', %b)";

    try {
        stm = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ITEM (ID, TYPE, TITEL, UITGELEEND) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

        for (int n = 0; n < ItemLijst.getItems().size(); n++) {
            Item huidigItem = ItemLijst.getItemObvIdx(n);

            stm.setString(1, huidigItem.getID().toString());
            stm.setString(2, huidigItem.getType().toString());
            stm.setString(3, huidigItem.getTitel());
            stm.setString(4, String.valueOf(huidigItem.isUitgeleend()));
        }
        stm.executeUpdate();
        stm.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Or do I need to include the `executeUpdate()` in the loop? And the `PreparedStatement`? Or do I need to do an `executeBatch()`?

Answer (score 6):

Running a query inside a for loop is not the best practice. It is better if you use batch update as the following:

```
stm = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ITEM (ID, TYPE, TITEL, UITGELEEND) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
db.setAutoCommit(false);  
for (int n = 0; n < ItemLijst.getItems().size(); n++) {
     Item huidigItem = ItemLijst.getItemObvIdx(n);
     stm.setString(1, huidigItem.getID().toString());
     stm.setString(2, huidigItem.getType().toString());
     stm.setString(3, huidigItem.getTitel());
     stm.setString(4,String.valueOf(huidigItem.isUitgeleend()));
     stm.addBatch();
     }
stm.executeBatch();
db.commit();
```

Comment: Why the commit()? I used executeBatch() before and it worked without the commit.

Comment: It is better to disable autocommit first before beginning the prepared statement. And then once everything is done, you should commit the transaction.

Comment: Refer to the auto commit part of the page : http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/08/top-10-jdbc-best-practices-for-java.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `executeUpdate` for each item in the list, so it needs to be inside the loop. You only need to prepare the statement once so that should be outside of the loop.

So:

```
try {
    stm = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ITEM (ID, TYPE, TITEL, UITGELEEND) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    for (int n = 0; n < ItemLijst.getItems().size(); n++) {
        Item huidigItem = ItemLijst.getItemObvIdx(n);

        stm.setString(1, huidigItem.getID().toString());
        stm.setString(2, huidigItem.getType().toString());
        stm.setString(3, huidigItem.getTitel());
        stm.setString(4, String.valueOf(huidigItem.isUitgeleend()));

        stm.executeUpdate();
    }
    stm.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Another possibility is to use addBatch/executeBatch, in which case you call addBatch inside the loop, then call executeBatch outside the loop. In my own programs, though, I tend to do what you did, putting the executeUpdate inside the loop. Lastly, there is the question of when to perform the transaction commit.

Comment: If you want to call `getGeneratedKeys()` on the `PreparedStatement`, would you call that outside of the loop? Or after each iteration (ie: within the loop)?