# Is there any advantage in using addBatch() and executeBatch() over executing multiple queries sequentially?

Tags: java, sqlite

I came across a scenario where I have to insert 20 rows into a database (SQLite). The approach I followed was to create an `update` method which would take a `String` and a `float` and set them in a `PreparedStatement`. I used to call this update method 20 times to insert all the  rows. This is my update method:

```java
void update(String variableName, int value) throws SQLException {
    String query = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Table1 (STRINGNAME, VALUE) VALUES(?,?)";
    try (Connection connection = getDataSource().getConnection(); 
         PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);) {
        pst.setString(1, variableName);
        pst.setInt(2, value);
        pst.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

I got to know that there is a provision to add multiple queries in a batch and execute the whole batch using `addBatch` and `executeBatch` methods provided by `PreparedStatement`.

As per my understanding, `addBatch` will add an SQL query to the current list of commands for the `Statement` object and `executeBatch` will execute all the queries in the list. Isn't this equivalent to calling the `update` method multiple times (Other than maybe the initialisation of `PreparedStatement`)? Is there any performance advantage in using `addbatch` and `executeBatch` over executing the `update` method multiple times?

#### Update

I tested both the scenarios: one with batch update and one with a modified version of the `update` method for 20000 queries.

`updateCommon`, modified `update` method with common `PreparedStatment`:

```java
void updateCommon(String variableName, int value, PreparedStatement pst) throws SQLException {      
    pst.setString(1, variableName);
    pst.setInt(2, value);
    pst.executeUpdate();
}
```

`updateBatch` method, where data is added to batch:

```java
void updateBatch(String variableName, float value, PreparedStatement pst) throws SQLException {     
    pst.setString(1, variableName);
    pst.setInt(2, value);
    pst.addBatch();
}
```

###### Testing

`updateCommon` test was done as follows:

```java
try {
    Connection conn = getDataSource().getConnection();
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        updateCommon("String1" + i, 1, pst);
        /*
        * till 20
        */
        updateCommon("String20" + i, 20, pst);
    }
}
```

`updateBatch` test was done as follows:

```java
try (Connection conn = getDataSource().getConnection(); PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query); ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        updateBatch("String1" + i, 1, pst);
        /*
        * till 20
        */
        updateBatch("String20" + i, 20, pst);
    }
    pst.executeBatch();
}
```

###### Result:

Time taken by `updateCommon` method for completion of test: 117.2 seconds 
Time taken by `updateBatch` method for completion of test: 267.6 seconds

This further makes the question more interesting as it seems like, direct update with a common `PreparedStatement` is almost twice faster in this specific use case.

Therefore, Is there any advantage in using addBatch() and executeBatch() over executing multiple queries sequentially?

Comment: Based on my testing, it seems that there is a loss if we use batch. Check the update in the question.

Comment: So can it be concluded that we can't definitely say which would give better performance as it depends completely on which Database we are using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an performance advantage.
Calling your update-method 20 times will execute 20 Insert-Statements.

Using the addBatch/executeBatch way, only one Insert-Statement gets executed which will insert 20 Lines at once, this is faster.

Allthough you might not recognize a difference with 20 Lines, you will with several 1000 Lines.

Comment: I did some testing using both the cases. For multi-update, I used a common connection and a common prepared statement. In that case, multi-update has almost double the speed when executing 20000 instructions.